CSS :where selector overrides :host selector
When I create a custom element like this:
customElements.define(
  'my-custom-element',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
      shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<style>:host {color: blue;}</style>Text which should be blue, but it's red.`;
    }
  }
);

and create a global style with a :where selector
:where(my-custom-element) {
  color: red;
}

My :host selector gets overwritten even with the zero specificity selector.
Running exaple
How can I write a selector so that my styles are not overwritten.

:host by design has less specificity because the user owns the Component and thus can set/override CSS on <my-component> If you want the Author to be in charge use !important inside :host Or add an extra DOM element layer inside your shadowRoot you can then style with <style> iniside shadowRoot

Has less specificity than zero?

I think they called it No Specificity https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1915
